# How do I run a script using another script in linux?

Tags: linux, scripting

My script is:

```
/opt/Myapplication/bin/start.sh
```

I always have to start it this way:

```
$cd /opt/Myapplication
$bin/start.sh
```

Now I want to write a script, which will run start.sh as above. I mean, it should run it from `/opt/Myapplication` directory

Maybe like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_path=/opt/Myapplication
$my_path/bin/start.sh
```

Will it run start.sh from `/opt/Myapplication` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will run `/opt/Myapplication/my_path/bin/start.sh`, but it won't change the working directory, if that's what you mean. To do that, you'll have to `cd` in the script first:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_path=/opt/Myapplication
cd $my_path
$my_path/bin/start.sh
```

Comment: maybe ./bin/start.sh in last line?

Comment: that doesn't really make any difference, it just uses the relative path instead of the absolute, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid scripts that need to be in a specific location to work properly

But no it will not run with that working directory, you have to cd first

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/Myapplication/bin
bash start.sh
```

Comment: No, I must run it from /opt/Myapplication directory.

Comment: Use a subshell if you want to avoid cwd pollution: `(cd /opt/Myapplication && ./start.sh)`